# Is it possible to disable drive signature verification on Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, drivers, digital-signature

When **installing drivers**, sometimes we need for the system to **not ask for confirmation** to the user (i.e: unattended or remote installations).
A good example of this is the TAP network driver for Windows used on [OpenVPN](https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/downloads.html).

I have found [methods](https://support.hidemyass.com/hc/en-us/articles/202723596-How-to-disable-Driver-Signing-check-on-Windows) to disable this driver check for any **pre-8 Windows**. For Windows 8 it **keeps requesting** for the user to accept installation.

Is there any method to **disable** this on Windows 8 (or later)?

**Command-line** methods preferred. GUI accepted, by the way.

Comment: [This method should work](http://www.howtogeek.com/167723/how-to-disable-driver-signature-verification-on-64-bit-windows-8.1-so-that-you-can-install-unsigned-drivers/).  I should point out it is  the same method for Windows 8.0 also.  Even when you allow unsigned drivers, a previliaged user, will still have to install them.

Comment: I don't understand you, @Ramhound . Maybe you made some mistake in your last phrase?

Comment: @Ramhound, I think your link makes the same effect as mine: `When you install the driver, this prompt will appear on screen.`. I would like to not appear any prompt at all.

Comment: Install the driver for the user then ahead of time then.

Answer (score 0):

I bumped into this but the way I did it only was a one-time deal. When rebooted, I had to disable driver verification manually again.

The method I used:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NM1MN8QZhnk

seeing the procedure in video is more clear but to put in words:

1. press windows key+c. will open tab menu on the right
2. click 'change pc settings'
3. click general on the left menu
4. in Advanced Startup click 'restart now' button
5. After restarting, A screen with multiple options in metro UI will appear
6. click Troubleshoot
7. Goto Advanced Options
8. goto 'startup settings'
9. click 'restart'
10. type the number corresponding to 'disable driver signature enforcement'

steps 1~4 can be replaced by clicking 'restart'  among power off options with shift key pressed.

As for command line options, I'm not aware of any.

Comment: I think this method is the same referred to in my link on the original question, and, as can be seen at the end of it, it keeps prompting: `When you install the driver, this prompt will appear on screen.`